# Does a continuous tense fit with my sentence

Tags: continuous

> For the past two days, I had been hearing some scary sounds after waking up and it frightened me. I'm glad today I have not heard them.

Is it possible to use the continuous tense as it happened more than one, and despite the sounds did not last long .

But may be continuous is not require when there is "for the past two days" which already indicates that it is a repetitive event and to use a continuous tense the sounds should last a long time

Answer (score 0):

For the past two days, I have been hearing some scary sounds after waking up and it frightens me. You have to use present perfect continuous, not past perfect continuous, because you are talking about the present.

You use the continuous, because you have been hearing these sounds for the past two days, which expresses duration. Even if the sounds didn't last long.